# Laying out 2 UIButtons in Xcode storyboard issue

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am having a couple of issues with the layout of my app, I have a few views that I layed out no problem using the 'add missing constraints' option in Xcode. Now I have a view with 2 buttons and I can't seem to get it right..I will point out now I am self teaching myself so apologies if this is straight forward. I can't post images yet so I'll try and explain below what I want

```
-----------------------------------------------
|
|
|    ----------------       ----------------
|       button 1               button 2
|    ----------------       ----------------
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
```

Apologies for crude drawing but this is how the buttons look in storyboard, if I run the simulator only button1 is visible, if I use the 'add missing constraints' option the buttons end up on top of each other..any help would be appreciated. Thank you
Great thanks for the up vote here are images!

This is what I want
[image]

and this is what I get without contraints (and suggestion below)

[image]

and this is what happens when I add missing constraints with Xcode

[image]

UPDATE: Okay guys, thank you for all the comments and answers, Between @Travis M. and @Fogmeister I have figured out the whole constraints section of Xcode.I really appreciate. Technically neither of ye answered the question here so I don't particularly know what to do as regards marking an answer. @Fogmeister switched the lightbulb on above head though so credit to him...Thanks

Comment: Haha, great "drawing" 

Comment: Ha! Thanks, glad you got a chuckle from it!

Comment: Search SO for "centring multiple views with auto layout". I have answered this exact question about 5 times.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you want the buttons? If you want to basically appear how you laid them out on any canvas, then I would highlight both buttons and in Storyboard tap on third button in lower right (looks like triangle inside of goalpost) and select "Clear Constraints From Selected Views".

Then select tap on the second button and select these items to set them up as you laid them out.

[image]

I think the issue is that "Add Missing Constraints" tries to make some educated guesses on what your alignments might be and it's sometimes wrong.

Also, make sure you have no alignment/constraint warnings. if you do, you're still missing something (maybe a parent view of the buttons, etc).

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to have any effect, button 1 is centered in the simulator and button 2 is not visible, if you uproot question I think I have enough points to post images

Comment: Do you have any constraint warnings? little yellow triangle on the left panel next to the view controller? Typically when it's behaving oddly, I highlight the ViewController and Remove all Constaints (wipe it clean) then start creating constraints from scratch.

Comment: No warnings, something I have noticed through experimenting though is that if I clear everything from the view controller and then add a button literally anywhere it always ends up centered, this made have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think that it's really centered. Try rotating the simulator to landscape or trying a different device (from iPhone to iPad) you'll likely see that it isn't really centered. However, what you're talking about is a bit strange, can you post screenshots?

Comment: LOVED YOU. I didn't know those dotted things were clickable.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post images :-( need 2 more points

Answer (score 0):

Check your view hierarchy and make sure that the UIButton's are in the same super-view. I would also manually set the constraints in Interface Builder:
- click on the 'width' and 'height' check-boxes
- set the 'left' and 'top' spacing values ("Use Standard Value")